# How to get the ssm parameter to a yaml file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a yaml cloud formation file which requires a variable stored in ssm parameter. The yaml file is a CFT template. Below is the sample code,

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: 'Fully Automated OT Archival Data Migration'
Parameters:
 Environment:
  Description: 'Stage type (for Tags)'
  Type: String
  Default: dev

Resources:
S3Bucket:
 Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
 Properties:
  BucketName: '{{resolve:ssm:/opentext/config/automated-ot-archival-data-migration/migration.bucket.name:1}}-${Environment}'
```

When I upload the code to cloudformation in AWS console, I results with an error. I'm wondering whether the ssm param reference is correct or not.

Please let me know if you find any issues here.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the `!Sub` function for your `{Environment}` variable.

```
BucketName: !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/opentext/config/automated-ot-archival-data-migration/migration.bucket.name:1}}-${Environment}'
```